# Html2Canvas and jsPDF add 1 image per page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf, html2canvas

i am using jsPDF and html2canvas (0.4.1) to save images inside a dive to a sinlge pdf.

So far my code works almost ok, but i have one problem.

When the user choose more than one image, images saved in one page. So i want every image in different page. My code is:

```
<div id="imagesPreview"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#modalSave").click(function(){

var inputValue = $('#form29').val()
var imagesnumber = $("#imagesPreview img").length;
//alert(imagesnumber);

var imgData;
html2canvas(document.getElementById("imagesPreview"),{
    useCORS: true,
    onrendered:function(canvas){
    imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    //Make The Pdf Document
    var doc = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');

    if (imagesnumber > 1){
        var i;
        for (i = 1; i < imagesnumber; i++) 
        {
        doc.addImage(imgData,'PNG',10,10)[i];
        doc.addPage()[i];
        }
    }else{
        doc.addImage(imgData,'PNG',10,10);
    }

        if($('#inputValue').val() == ''){
    doc.save('MyPdf.pdf');
    }else{
    doc.save(inputValue+'.pdf');
    }
    window.open(imgData);
    }

    })

});
});
</script>
```

i am using imagesnumber to count the number of images inside the div.

Any idea please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

1. Loop through all the images
2. Make a canvas to PNG of each as you go
3. Add each of these to the PDF as you go
4. Check to see if the array length has more images to come. If so, `addPage()`
5. Add a `then()` method to make sure it saves the PDF only after everything has been done. Also, in this `then()` method, check to see where the loop index is at, so that you only save the PDF after the last image has been added.

> In my example, those two little blue blocks will be the images that
>   gets added to the PDF. Now, this example won't run on Stack Overflow
>   due to sandbox limitations, but you can see the [working JSFiddle
>   here.](https://jsfiddle.net/Ludolfyn/4hgvaxtj/)

```js
const imgs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.img')]
const btn = document.querySelector('a')

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const doc = new jsPDF()
    imgs.forEach((a, i) => {
        html2canvas(a)
        .then(canvas => {
            const img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
            doc.addImage(img,'PNG', 45, 45, 100, 100);
            if (imgs.length > (i+1)) {
                doc.addPage()
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            if ((i+1) === imgs.length) {
                doc.save('MyPdf.pdf')
            }
        })
    })
})
```

```css
span {width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color: blue; display: inline-block}
a {display: block}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js" integrity="sha384-NaWTHo/8YCBYJ59830LTz/P4aQZK1sS0SneOgAvhsIl3zBu8r9RevNg5lHCHAuQ/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<span class="img"></span>
<span class="img"></span>
<a href="#">Download PDF</a>
```

> **UPDATE**

Here's how to do the same thing with `<img>` tags, instead of using Html2canvas to create images. In this example you don't need Html2canvas at all. I've updated the above JSFiddle link to show this example.

```js
const imgs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.img')]
const btn = document.querySelector('a')

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const doc = new jsPDF()
    let dataUrl
    async function makeImg(img) {
        let blob = await fetch(img.src).then(res => res.blob());
        dataUrl = await new Promise(resolve => {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        })
    }
    imgs.forEach((a, i) => {
        makeImg(a)
        .then(res => {
            doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'PNG', 45, 45, a.style.width, a.style.height)
            if (imgs.length > (i+1)) {
                doc.addPage()
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            if ((i+1) === imgs.length) {
                doc.save('MyPdf.pdf')
            }
        })
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js" integrity="sha384-NaWTHo/8YCBYJ59830LTz/P4aQZK1sS0SneOgAvhsIl3zBu8r9RevNg5lHCHAuQ/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<img class="img" src="https://i.postimg.cc/NfMXcB4c/Screenshot-2020-06-09-at-18-35-56.png">
<img class="img" src="https://i.postimg.cc/NfMXcB4c/Screenshot-2020-06-09-at-18-35-56.png">
<a href="#" style="display: block">Download PDF</a>
```

Comment: if i replace your spans with images and left the classname img, it doesn't work. I Get Blank pages in the exported pdf. Any idea?

Comment: Hey @YeorgiosLaskos .. Uhmmmm, I do actually have an idea of what it might be. I think it's because the html2canvas renders an HTML element to a `<canvas>` element and then to an actual image—when you use actual images from the start, then html2canvas is having trouble rendering them to be `<canvas>` elements. What I think the solution could be is to create data URLs of those images with the `toDataUrl()` method first, in which case you might actually not need html2canvas. It's bedtime where I am, but I can try and figure it out and then update the answer in the morning if that's cool?

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy for your time.. please update your code when you find some spare time. Unfortunately i can't  press the up arrow in your answer coz it needs 15+ reputation... :-(

Comment: Only a pleasure brother =) I'm going to see if I can figure it out quick and update the answer. Ah and thanks for trying at least man, I appreciate it. I'm going to upvote your question, because the fact that no one else answered means that it's a tricky problem and a good question. It will give you some points ;) It won't be enough, but you'll have some more points.

Comment: @YeorgiosLaskos I've figured it out and updated the answer. I hope it helps man. Shout if you need some more help =)